# String replace in php after "[||]"

Tags: php, regex

I am getting a unique issue. I have string like "Home[||](|i am in here|)[||]". Now i want to replace everything after first occurance from left of '[||]' with null. Tried many ways like pregreplace,substring,explode,strstr,strreplace... But nothing seems to work out. Can someone please help.

Comment: post your expected output

Comment: I need "Home" from this...

Comment: then what about this way? `echo explode('[||]',"Home[||](|i am in here|)[||]")[0];` without any kind of `regex` or `str_*` function

Comment: Yes this works.

Comment: You want NULL or an empty string? Where is your current code?

Answer (score 1):

Using [`strstr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) would be about the simplest...

```
echo strstr("Home[||](|i am in here|)[||]", "[||]", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to find the part of the string you want to replace.

```
<?php
$input = "Home[||](|i am in here|)[||]";
$pattern = "/\[\|\|\](.*)/";
$output = preg_replace($pattern, "", $input);
echo $output;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by many way using [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php), [strtok()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php), [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)  etc. But I would prefer with [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), without any kind of `regex` or `str_*` function to achieve what you want. Hope this will help to get your job done.

```
echo explode('[||]',"Home[||](|i am in here|)[||]")[0];
```

**DEMO:** https://eval.in/1040308

With **strtok()**

```
<?php
$mystring = 'Home[||](|i am in here|)[||]';
$first = strtok($mystring, '[||]');
echo $first; // Home
?>
```

With **strstr()**:

```
 <?php
$mystring = 'Home[||](|i am in here|)[||]';
$first = strstr($mystring, "[||]", true);
echo $first; // Home
?>
```